# Trigger « if last char is whitespace and » if not

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to print either **«** or **»** whenever I press `Shift+Numpad7`.

I know how to set up two different scripts: e.g. `+Numpad7::«` and `+Numpad8::»`, but is there a way to have the output depend on whether the character before the caret is whitespace or not?

I.e., so I could type something like **«Hello»**, where both times I pressed `Shift+Numpad7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shifting numpad numbers can have unintended overrides (like on my system) so I used `Ctrl Numpad7`, but YMMV:

```
^Numpad7::
    oldClip := Clipboard ; save current clipboard
    Send, +{Left}^c{right} ; select char to the left and copy to clipboard
    ClipWait
    lchar := Clipboard = " " ? "«" : "»" ; check if space or not
    Send, %lchar% ; send lchar
    clipboard := oldClip ; restore original clipboard
    ClipWait
return
```

Btw, since unicode and ansi vers of AHK handle that character differently, on some systems you may get an extra preceding character in the output.  Just change the last Send to:

```
    Send, % SubStr(lchar, 0) ; send last character of lchar
```

And let us know what version worked for you.